# Is there a way to graphically visually integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, visualization, substitution

In integration by substitution, we change the variable. For example:
$$\int_{x^{2}=0}^{x^{2}=9} x^{2} d(x^{2})=\int_{x=0}^{x=3} x^{2} \dfrac{d(x^{2})}{dx}dx$$ 
Here since we have two different variables I find it impossible to graphically visualize how integration by substitution works.

Is there any other way to visualize this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Draw both graphs and mark the limits. Then you get two equal areas (At least in the given case)

Comment: That's right. But that doesn't give a graphical intuition on why we are getting equal areas.

Comment: A graphical intuition would only be possible by changing the scale of the axis, but in thic case, the change of the scales would not be intuitive. I do not think that such an intuition you want is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plot below shows, in a Cartesian $(x, u, y)$-space, the change-of-variables identity
$$
\int_{x = a}^{x = b} f(g(x)) g'(x)\, dx = \int_{u = g(a)}^{u = g(b)} f(u)\, du
\tag{1}
$$
for the region $R$ defined by $0 \leq y \leq f(u)$ for $g(a) \leq u \leq g(b)$ in the $(u, y)$-plane.

The integral on the left side of (1) represents the parametrization of $R$ by the region $R_{0}$ defined by $0 \leq y \leq f(x)$ for $a \leq x \leq b$ in the $(x, y)$-plane. To get the area of $R$ as an integral over $R_{0}$, send the point $(x, y)$ to $(u, y) = (g(x), y)$. As the shaded areas indicate, the vertical strip of $R_{0}$ at location $x$ is scaled in width (hence in area) by $g'(x)$.

[image: The geometry of change of variables]

Comment: What is meant by parametrization of $R$ by $R_{0}$? How is it that the integral on the left side of (1) represents the parametrization of $R$ by $R_{0}$?

Comment: The area of $R_{0}$ is $\int_{a}^{b} f(g(x))\, dx$. Each point $(x, y)$ of $R_{0}$ corresponds to a unique point $(u, y) = (g(x), y)$ of $R$, but (in the language of infinitesimals) this mapping sends the thin vertical strip of height $f(g(x))$, between $x$ and $x + dx$, to the thin vertical strip of height $f(g(x))$ between $g(x)= u$ and $g(x + dx) = u + du = u + g'(x)\, dx$. The area of $R$ is therefore $\int_{a}^{b} f(g(x)) g'(x)\, dx$, the integral of the areas of the images of the thin strips.

Comment: I get it. What seemed impossible turned out to be very simple. Thanks a million.

Comment: +1. This is great! What tool do you use for the figure?

Comment: @ripples I'm happy the answer was useful! The figure was made with [ePiX](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html).